# scala List zipWithIndex different results?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val df = Seq(

        (1, "A, B, C, D"), 
        (2, "E, F, G,5"), 
        (3, "H, I,5,7"), 
        (4, "J,sd,cc,23")
).toDF("number","letters")
df.show()
```

```
output:
+------+----------+
|number|   letters|
+------+----------+
|     1|A, B, C, D|
|     2| E, F, G,5|
|     3|  H, I,5,7|
|     4|J,sd,cc,23|
+------+----------+
```

```
val arr = df.filter($"number"===1).select($"letters").head.toSeq
val list1 = arr.toList
list1.zipWithIndex
```

// why there is not  List( ("A",0),("B",1),("C",2),("D",3) ) ?

```
output:
arr: Seq[Any] = WrappedArray(A, B, C, D)
list1: List[Any] = List(A, B, C, D)
res87: List[(Any, Int)] = List((A, B, C, D,0))
```

however

```
List("a", "b", "c").zipWithIndex
output:
    res88: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,0), (b,1), (c,2))
```

Why are they all zipwithindex with different output formats?

Comment: Maybe you want to save a list instead of a string in your DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.head` on a DataFrame you are returning a `Row`.

If you look at the size of `list1` you will see it only contains a single element.

You need to extract the String at element 0 of the Row:

```
df
  .filter($"number"===1)
  .select($"letters")
  .head
  .getString(0)
  .split(",")
  .zipWithIndex
```